# CSOM / REST / Web Service Support for Auditing

Tags: csom, auditing, sharepoint-rest-api

I came to know from the below link that Microsoft has added CSOM / REST support for Auditing APIs in the future versions. By future versions, do they mean only 2016 or even 2013 also? Any idea? Has anyone seen any APIs or code samples? Any idea, how to get these things for earlier versions like 2007 / 2010?

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/5720293-csom-and-rest-provide-spchange-and-spaudit-functio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs mentioned are for SharePoint online via the Office 365 Management APIs.

There is no client API for directly querying audit logs in any version of on prem. That may change for 2016 but I wouldn't bet on it.

If you have access to the Server OM you can use Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery. It is also present in 2010 and 2007.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please shed some more light into Office 365 Management APIs for Auditing, possibly with some code samples?

Comment: You can get samples from MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt227394.aspx